# Install python 2.7 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

is there a way to install Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 18.04? 
I tried this command but it isn't working.

```
sudo apt install python-minimal
```

Is there a way to install it manually? I try python 2.7 for a software that didn't support python 3.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, which software? Python 2 is end-of-life as of a few days ago, and given how long the phase-out period was, there's a good chance there's a more modern alternative.

Comment: The dataplicity client. They say it is under development (the client application)

Comment: you should consider using conda or virtualenv. Messing with system python for limited use on one module is too much.

Comment: "Isn't working" how? What do you mean by "install manually" and how is this not an expample of that?

Comment: I get this message with the command: The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2) but 2.7.17-1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: From [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/451078/1006720), they recommend to try with aptitude : `sudo aptitude install python-minimal`

Comment: @Jona this worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 26):

Run these commands to ensure your repositories are up to date before installing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python2.7
```

Then to install pip for python 2:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Comment: I get this message: The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2) but 2.7.17-1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You might have some python 2 packages installed already. Try `sudo apt purge python2.7-minimal` then install again

Answer (score 1):

As my comment has solved the issue, I will develop it a little more in this answer for further reference.

Try using aptitude, it better manage conflicting packages for you:

```
sudo aptitude install python-minimal
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/451078/1006720