# After deleting python in ubuntu 18.04 terminal and some other functionalities does not work

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in my work computer. I have never used Python2 versions before and it was annoying me to have in my computer because whenever I try to install something related Python I got issue even my default version Python3.6
I could not install pip, I could not install some packages so I wanted to delete Python completely from my computer. However now I can not install any python and getting lots of errors while trying several methods which are shared before on this platform and other websites.

Currently my terminal does not work so I use Xterm.

```
python --version
```

> bash /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

```
whereis python
```

> python: /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

```
sudo apt install python-minimal
```

[image]

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

[image]

```
sudo apt update
```

[image]

I have tried many things I have seen on the web but could not fix. Also I am user in this computer so I do not have root access. Just wanted to know how to fix.

Comment: unrelated to the borked install (well not completely) but these situations are exactly why `virtualenv` was conceived. Next time don't go nuclear on your install (there's a reason why python2 is included in Ubuntu 18.04) but use a `virtualenv`. Besides that, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59632121/9267296)

Comment: "I wanted to delete Python completely from my computer" - it seems you did that. How did you uninstall it?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy the text instead.

Comment: @ThomasWeller It does not allow me to copy it and it is too long to write one by one so i included pictures.

I delete it using " sudo rm -rf /location of python

I checked locations whereis python.

deleted it one by one.

Comment: Who does not allow you to copy? The shell? Can't believe ...

Comment: Well, if you mess that much with your system without understanding how it works, you should probably set it up from scratch again.